# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, next.js

I am using nextjs and nodejs with MongoDB, I am trying to create API inside pages/API path but I get undefined, How I can fix it, thank you..........................................................

```js
require("dotenv").config();
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

let dbconection;

module.exports = {
  connectDB: function (callback) {
    const url = process.env.DB;
    MongoClient.connect(url)
      .then((client) => {
        dbconection = client.db();
        return callback();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        return callback(err);
      });
  },
  getDB: function(){
    return dbconection
  }
};
```

```js
require('dotenv').config()
const mongodb = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const {connectDB, getDB } = require('../../../utils/connectdb')

connectDB()


export default async (req, res)=>{


    const data = await getDB().collection('products').find().toArray((err, result)=>{
        console.log(result)
    })
    res.status(200).json({products: data})

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're calling connectDB() which returns immediately (because it's async).
You don't 'wait' until dbconnection is being set.
Therefore getDB returns undefined.
You'd need a different approach, I'm afraid.

There might be cooler approaches, but maybe try this:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

let dbconection;

module.exports = {
  connectDB: function (callback) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (dbconnection) {
       resolve();
    }
    const url = process.env.DB;
    MongoClient.connect(url)
      .then((client) => {
        dbconection = client.db();
        resolve();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        reject(err);
      });
    });
  },
  getDB: function(){
    return dbconection
  }
};
```

And then

```
require('dotenv').config()
const {connectDB, getDB } = require('../../../utils/connectdb')



export default async (req, res)=>{
    connectDB()
      .then(()=>{
       const data = await getDB().collection('products').find().toArray((err, result)=>{
        console.log(result)
      })
    })
    res.status(200).json({products: data})
}
```